# Does google index dynamic content under anchor links?

Tags: seo, google-search

I have a JS generated page with modal windows. Modal window in this case is a plain popup, which code inserted in main page by the script. Modal window opens by clicking on an anchor link (e.g. `<a href="#somewindow">open window</a>`). It does not change the url (so when it opens the url still will be `mysite.com/home#somewindow` ). Window code is not present on original page.

1. Will content of these windows be indexed?
2. Will these windows appear in search results as different pages?
3. Should I include these URLs in "sitemap.xml" file?

Comment: Is this an actual "window", or just an HTML div-like "popup" on the same page? Does the URL change when these "windows" appear (#3 implies that it does)?

Comment: It is an HTML inserted by the script in the main page. It does not change the URL. Updated description. Thanks! P.S. #3 implies that if I have a `/home` URL in sitemap, should I also include `/home#somewindow` for modal window content to be indexed?